# Django: Passing URL parameters to app URL handler

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am trying to follow along to the book "[Lightweight Django](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920032502.do)", and in Chapter 2, the Django application intercepts URLs in the project-level `urls.py` and calls a view `placeholder`:

```
    url(r'^image/(?P<width>[0-9]+)x(?P<height>[0-9]+)/$', 
     placeholder)
```

where `placeholder` is a view that exists in the project-level `views.py`.

I am trying to organize the project differently so that the URL intercepted at the project-level gets passed to the app-level `picture_server/urls.py`, where `picture_server` is the name of the app.

```
    url(r'^image/(?P<width>[0-9]+)x(?P<height>[0-9]+)/$', include(picture_server.urls))
```

It is then passed to the app-level view function, `picture_server/views.py`, which contains the view:

```
def placeholder(request, width, height):
  return(HttpResponse('Ok'))
```

What I am unsure of, is how to write the URL handling in `picture_server/urls.py` so that it calls the `placeholder` view with the right parameters:

```
url(r'^$', views.placeholder)
```

Will the parameters intercepted at the project-level be transmitted to the app-level `urls.py` to transfer to the `placeholder` view?

Comment: Yes, they will. Did you try?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have tried now, and it does indeed work. I guess I am not sure _why_ it works or how. References welcome. Would it work if I parsed part of the URL at the project level and part at the app level?

Comment: Django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs. Also, change `...<height>[0-9]+)/$` to `...<height>[0-9]+)/`.

Comment: @f43d65 Thanks -- was slowly making my way through that page. Helps to have the exact section to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have pointed out, the problem is that your project level pattern contains a `$` but it should not when using `include`.

> Will the parameters intercepted at the project-level be transmitted to the app-level urls.py to transfer to the placeholder view?

Yes they will. No you shouldn't do this. It makes it difficult to read/comprehend the urls. It also makes it required that all of the app level included url/views accept the height/width parameters. Currently there is only a single view in your `placeholder` app but if you added another which didn't accept these parameters and included it in the `placeholder/urls.py` it would break in an unexpected way.

Comment: Yes, I have changed the handling at the project-level to just parse `image/` and parameters are collected at the app-level now.