# Django: Client-side caching using etags

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

[More questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934541/django-passing-url-parameters-to-app-url-handler) as I work through [Lightweight Django](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920032502.do). In chapter 2, the book talks about client-side caching using the  `django.views.decorators.http.etag` decorator. I wrote the the following view:

```
import hashlib
import PIL.ImageDraw as ImageDraw
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest
from django import forms
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from django.views.decorators.http import etag

class ImageForm(forms.Form):
    """Form to vlaidate the requested placeholder image."""
    height = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, max_value=2000)
    width = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, max_value=2000)

    def generate(self, image_format="PNG"):
        """Generate an image of the given format and return raw bytes"""
        height = self.cleaned_data["height"]
        width = self.cleaned_data["width"]
        image = Image.new("RGB", (width, height)) # color is optional

        # create the key for the cached content
        cache_key = "{} x {} x {}".format(height, width, image_format)

        # add text around the image being served up
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
        text = "{} x {}".format(width, height)

        textwidth, textheight = draw.textsize(text)  # get the text size of the text
        if textwidth < width and textheight < height:
            texttop = (height - textheight) // 2
            textleft = (width - textwidth)  // 2
            draw.text((textleft, texttop), text, fill=(255, 255, 255))

        content = BytesIO()   
        image.save(content, image_format)
        content.seek(0)
        cache.set(cache_key, content, 60 * 60)
        return(content)

def etag_placeholder(request, width, height):
    content_to_hash = "Placeholder: {} x {}".format(width, height)
    return(hashlib.sha1(content_to_hash.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest())

@etag(etag_placeholder)
def placeholder(request, width, height):
    form = ImageForm({'height': height, "width": width})
    if form.is_valid():
        image = form.generate()
        return(HttpResponse(image, content_type="image/png"))
    else:
        return(HttpResponseBadRequest("Incorrect image dimensions requested."))
```

However, this view refuses to cache, and I continue to get 200 responses -- I am expecting to see 304s. Is there a setting that I am missing?

Comment: How are you requesting the page (browser, curl, wget)? curl/wget aren't going to send the original etag on the second request for you. Some browsers disable the cache (or have an option to) when the dev tools are open. You should check that isn't the case.

Comment: @MarkLavin I am using Chrome dev tools, and in the "Network" tab, the "Disable Cache"  is unchecked.

Comment: @MarkLavin Does it help to say that I am running my application locally?

Comment: It would help to show the server console output and the output from the network tab to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @MarkLavin Wait you are _the_ Mark Lavin. Thanks for the book -- demonstrates just the architecture that I was looking to learn. You might want to keep an eye out on this userid as I work my way through the book for the next few weeks. :-) For this question, I will add the output you requested.